# Generar nuevo archivo a partir de 2 listas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un controlador donde por medio de 2 `input` que tengo en mi vista, mando 2 archivos de tipo `excel` para poder obtener todas las celdas y columnas.

```
public ActionResult ArchivosExcel(HttpPostedFileBase archivo1, HttpPostedFileBase archivo2)
        {

            List<List<string>> filasArchivo1 = new List<List<string>>();
            List<List<string>> filasArchivo2 = new List<List<string>>();

            if (archivo1 != null && archivo1.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
                archivo1.InputStream.CopyTo(stream1);
                stream1.Position = 0;

                XSSFWorkbook libro1 = new XSSFWorkbook(stream1);
                ISheet hoja1 = libro1.GetSheetAt(0);

                for (int filaIndex = hoja1.FirstRowNum; filaIndex <= hoja1.LastRowNum; filaIndex++)
                {
                    IRow fila = hoja1.GetRow(filaIndex);
                    if (fila != null)
                    {
                        List<string> celdas = new List<string>();
                        for (int celdaIndex = fila.FirstCellNum; celdaIndex < fila.LastCellNum; celdaIndex++)
                        {
                            ICell celda = fila.GetCell(celdaIndex);
                            if (celda != null)
                            {
                                celdas.Add(celda.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        filasArchivo1.Add(celdas);
                    }
                }
                stream1.Close();
                libro1.Close();
            }

            if (archivo2 != null && archivo2.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
                archivo2.InputStream.CopyTo(stream2);
                stream2.Position = 0;

                XSSFWorkbook libro2 = new XSSFWorkbook(stream2);
                ISheet hoja2 = libro2.GetSheetAt(0);

                for (int filaIndex = hoja2.FirstRowNum; filaIndex <= hoja2.LastRowNum; filaIndex++)
                {
                    IRow fila = hoja2.GetRow(filaIndex);
                    if (fila != null)
                    {
                        List<string> celdas = new List<string>();
                        for (int celdaIndex = fila.FirstCellNum; celdaIndex <= fila.LastCellNum; celdaIndex++)
                        {
                            ICell celda = fila.GetCell(celdaIndex);
                            if (celda != null)
                            {
                                celdas.Add(celda.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        filasArchivo2.Add(celdas);
                    }
                }
                stream2.Close();
                libro2.Close();
            }

            var resultado = new
            {
                archivo1 = filasArchivo1,
                archivo2 = filasArchivo2
            };

            return Json(resultado);
        }
```

Y me genera un json de un objeto con 2 listas de los datos de los archivos de excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero poder seleccionar por ejemplo, poder seleccionar columnas de diferentes archivos y copiarlas a otro nuevo archivo de excel. Estoy utilizando la librería de `NPOI` para obtener las filas y celdas de los archivos de excel.

Comment: No entiendo el problema, favor dar más detalle del resultado esperado

Comment: Hola Yussef, ya edite la pregunta así que básicamente lo que estoy tratando de hacer es agarrar diferentes columnas de un archivo excel que ya tengo en unas listas y poder crear otro nuevo archivo excel, con columnas seleccionadas

Comment: A ver si entiendo, ¿envías 2 archivos excel y quieres recibir un JSON de la mezcla de ambos archivos?

Comment: Sí, envió 2 archivos excel pero el return con el json nada más lo puse para ver si me llegaban bien los datos. Pero mi problema es que no se como seleccionar columnas especificas de los 2 archivos y ponerlas en un nuevo archivo excel

Comment: Esto es tema extenso, al chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tan solo al final de la función en vez de que me retorne un `json`, es una función con las 2 listas de los 2 archivos.

```
return GenerarArchivo(filasArchivo1, filasArchivo2);
```

Y en la función de las listas obtenidas, las ordeno en otras listas para que cada una sea una columna.

```
public ActionResult GenerarArchivo(List<List<string>> filasArchivo1, List<List<string>> filasArchivo2)
        {
            List<string> listaCodigo = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaCodigo.Add(filasArchivo1[i][0]);
            }

            List<string> listaCodigoProveedor = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaCodigoProveedor.Add(filasArchivo1[i][14]);
            }

            List<string> listaCodigoXML = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaCodigoXML.Add("");
            }
            listaCodigoXML[0] = "Código XML";

            List<string> listaDescripcion = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaDescripcion.Add("");
            }
            listaDescripcion[0] = "Descripción";

            List<string> listaMarca = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaMarca.Add(filasArchivo1[i][12]);
            }

            List<string> listaPrecio = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo2.Count; i++)
            {
                listaPrecio.Add(filasArchivo2[i][12]);
            }
            listaPrecio[0] = "Precio lista";

            List<string> listaIncrementales = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaIncrementales.Add("");
            }
            listaIncrementales[0] = "Incrementales";

            List<string> listaMoneda = new List<string>();
            for( int i = 0; i < filasArchivo2.Count; i++)
            {
                listaMoneda.Add("USD");
            }
            listaMoneda[0] = "Moneda";

            List<string> listaMultiploDeCompra = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaMultiploDeCompra.Add("");
            }
            listaMultiploDeCompra[0] = "Múltiplo de compra";

            List<string> listaPrecioVenta = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo1.Count; i++)
            {
                listaPrecioVenta.Add("");
            }
            listaPrecioVenta[0] = "Precio venta";

            List<string> listaMonedaVenta = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filasArchivo2.Count; i++)
            {
                listaMonedaVenta.Add("USD");
            }
            listaMonedaVenta[0] = "Moneda de venta";

            var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Lista");

            for (int i = 0; i < listaCodigo.Count; i++)
            {
                var row = sheet.CreateRow(i);
                row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(listaCodigo[i]);
                row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(listaCodigoProveedor[i]);
                row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(listaCodigoXML[i]);
                row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(listaDescripcion[i]);
                row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(listaMarca[i]);
                row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(listaPrecio[i]);
                row.CreateCell(6).SetCellValue(listaIncrementales[i]);
                row.CreateCell(7).SetCellValue(listaMoneda[i]);
                row.CreateCell(8).SetCellValue(listaMultiploDeCompra[i]);
                row.CreateCell(9).SetCellValue(listaPrecioVenta[i]);
                row.CreateCell(10).SetCellValue(listaMonedaVenta[i]);
            }


            var correo = (User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity).Name;
            var agenteId = db.Agentes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Correo == correo).AgenteId;


            using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.Write(memoryStream);
                var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

                var archivo = new ListaDePrecios
                {
                    AgenteId = agenteId,
                    Fecha = DateTime.Now,
                    ArchivoByte = bytes,
                    Nombre = "PrecioLista - " + DateTime.Now,
                };

                db.ListaDePrecios.Add(archivo);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Comment: ¡Bien muchacho! Aprendes rápido :D